# Have horizontal RadioButtons wrap if too long for screen

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have the following radiobuttons. I want to have them display like this:

[image]

However this occurs:

[image: radiogroup problem]

How I can get it to display like above? 
I can move in the GUI editor in Eclipse it but it removes the RadioButton from the RadioGroup!
Within the group, it ignores all other layout parameters.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timeBar"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/privRadio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Everyone" />

    <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/privRadio1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="FriendOfFriends" />


 <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/privRadio2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Friends" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can simply copy this class:

https://github.com/jevonbeck/AbstractMachine/blob/jevon_dev/app/src/main/java/org/ricts/abstractmachine/ui/utils/MultiLineRadioGroup.java

into an appropriate package in your project and instantiate in XML like so:

```
<view
    class="mypackage.packagepath.MultiLineRadioGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

Comment: Looks like great code, but doesn't really accommodate for margins for the RadioButtons in the RadioGroup.

Comment: This works fine except when setting drawable selectors on the radio buttons, then it doesnt run. Any solution to this?

Comment: This has some issues when used programmatically. For instance, `OnCheckedChangeListener` gives incorrect index when radio button changed at runtime. Another issue is, `margin` is lost when inflating buttons through code.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is a [FlowLayout](http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/flowlayout-in-android/). Such a layout has the benefit of only wrapping when it's needed, as opposed to 0gravity's more "static" solution.

Comment: Interesting, is it possible to use this inside a RadioGroup?

Comment: I believe it's not, but it is possible to use RadioButtons without assigning them to a group.

Comment: @TheRealKingK: If you sub-class a RadioGroup and implement the onMeasure() and onLayout() functions similarly to the FlowLayout, you will get the solution you are looking for. See my solution on this page.